# I want to be a developer (website and web application) and want to choose asp.net as a programming lang

Tags: web-development, language, recommendations

I want to be a developer (website and web application) and want to choose asp.net as a programming lang.

I am currently an intermediate web designer. My friend told me that there are many things in asp.net

My question is I am interested in **website and web application development**

Is there any specific thing I have to learn to be a web developer or I have to learn the whole. Also, what does a developer has to do? key skills if he choose asp.net?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Buy a good book, and just start with a real project. The questions will come to you sooner than later, but with a project you will have reason to sort them out. Probably the project will grow over time and in the end you will have learned the whole as you said.

If you are not already experienced in web hosting i would look for a provider instead of setting up a server myself. This way you can avoid a lot of troubles and you will write code that others can install as well, without special priviledges on the server.

As for ASP.net, you will need a windows server and they are normally more expensive than a Linux/Apache server. This may be, or may not be a problem for you.

Comment: You nailed it; free asp.net hosting is a pain to set up because of multiple concerns: security, resource managing, and licenses.

IIS (the typical asp web server) is kind-of-easy (and even free with most licenses) to set up on your local windows machine, but webmastering is different.